# Chrome webdriver issue in Selenium, python, with linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

(edits in the end)

I'm codng a simple automation with Selenium in Python; my operating system is Mint. The issue is that I can't get it to open the Google Chrome browser, version 75.0.3770.80.

I've tried installing both de correct webdriver version for my browser (75.0.3770.80) and the latest version. I've tried adding "desiredCapabilities" to the code too, but didn't work.

Here's the tricky part, I've removed any other things I wrote on the code so it becomes easier to see the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/home/pbx/Downloads/gchromedriver/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://google.com")

driver.close()
```

This fragment of the code should open the browser and go to google.com, but it doesn't even open the browser. Here's the error log

```
/home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/venv/bin/python /home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/ChromeBrowser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/ChromeBrowser", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/home/pbx/Downloads/gchromedriver/chromedriver")
  File "/home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pbx/Documentos/pythomation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Edit:

```
Selenium version- 3.141.0
Python version- 3.7.1
Webdriver- chromedriver_linux64.zip 2019-04-30 00:03:36 4.90MB  
ee28a86911127498409dc8623d39ea94
```

I can't use and older version of Google Chrome because the automation must test an extension that requires the latest Chrome version.

All permissions are granted to the driver (rwx) for all users

Comment: What are the permissions for the driver (`ls -ls /home/pbx/Downloads/gchromedriver/chromedriver`)? It should be executable for the user who starts selenium...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with `75.0.3770.80-1` versions of chrome and chromedriver on my rails app. I moved back to the previous versions i.e. `74.0.3729.169-1` for both chrome and chromedriver, and they worked. You can try that.